# can no longer drag post processing profile into CenterEyeAnchor in OVRCameraRig -> TrackingSpace, is there an alternative step?

Tags: unity, post-processing

The video https://youtu.be/gh4k0Q1Pl7E?t=120 shows a step where I need to drag a newly created `post-processing profile` into the `CenterEyeAnchor` section. I am aware this video is the demo using an older version of the `Post Processing Stack` package, so one can not longer add it as a component into anywhere. But I do not know an alternative to achieve the same step?
Is it not even necessary?
By not going with step, I got all darken objects (but have some light on some part of the objects if I add some sort of light) But still its very different than the complete light achieved in that video.

What I have
[image]

What the video show

[image]

I follow pretty much 100% in the video until that step adding post-processing profile setup.

I am very noobie in Unity.

I am using

```
Unity 2019.3.14
Post Processing 2.3.0
```

Comment: What happens if you ignore/skip this step? What do you see in your project where this option would have been?

Comment: I really have no idea lol trying to stick to the video 100% or if not big part of it so I can have same result and no crazy errors at the end... But if no one knows, I may just have to go without and see how far I can go...

Comment: "Seeing how far you can go" sounds like a good first step. If the result isn't satisfactory, edit your question to show how the result differs from what you need.

Comment: @DMGregory so everything I do are in darkness, seems its causing a side effect of not having "light"? But the video did not say add any light and he has light all show, but mine is just all black, everything with the color looks black. Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like you should try adding a light to your scene.

Comment: I did but I tried all the lights, none of them give same effect like the light in the video

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to show the effect in the video you want to achieve, and the effect you get with your current setup for contrast.